# Geometry in arcpy and pyQGIS

Tags: python, arcgis, qgis, arcpy, pyqgis

Question 1
Write a Python program using arcpy to find the south-most point for any given feature class. Test your code on at least two different types of features (points, lines, or polygons). The program must be run outside ArcGIS Pro. Submit the code in a .py file and screenshots showing your test results.

Question 2
Within our trt00_shp.shp shapefile, we want to find those tracts whose size is at least 5,000,000 but smaller than 50,000,000. Write a Python program (using arcpy) to print the OID value, the size, and the centroid coordinates of each of these tracts. Also, print out how many such tracts there are in the file. Submit your work in a .py file, and make sure to include all the printouts at the end of the file using a docstring.

Question 3
Write a Python program to do three things in QGIS:
First, it loads a point feature class from existing data (a point shapefile, for example) into QGIS as a layer. The name and the path to the data file can be fixed.
Second, now that the point layer is added, the program will draw a box (rectangle) that contains most of the points. By "most," we actually have something very specific: we draw a rectangle such that there is at least one outside of each of the four sides of the rectangle. The only time multiple points can be out of one side of the rectangle is when they all share the same X or Y coordinate. This rectangle will be added to QGIS as a polygon layer. The polygon (rectangle) has an attribute called "Name" and you can assign any value to that attribute.
Finally, after the previous two tasks are done, the program will post a log message that should contain the name of the two layers added and the number of points contained in the rectangle. Submit the Python code in .py and a screenshot. The screenshot must have the points, the rectangle, the Python code (not necessarily the entire code but some part of the code must be shown), the log message, the layers panel with the point and polygon layers listed, and the attribute tables where the table of the polygon layer is visible. You don't have to run your Python code line by line. Instead, please try to editor that comes with the Python console.

what would be the overall procedure of accomplishing the three questions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.